# Banner Grabbing Spoofing

Tags: windows-server-2008, spoofing, banner

I run a windows server 2008 standard R2. Is there a way to spoof the server banner ?

So instead of Microsoft-IIS/7.5 it could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google sez](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=IIS+custom+server+header) that it's different between IIS versions, but for IIS 7 you [can use a .NET module to modify the header as the request is processed](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2008/03/12/iis-7-how-to-send-a-custom-server-http-header.aspx).